# Is JavaScript viable for serious multiplatform 2D game development?

Tags: c++, game-design, javascript

Ever since I was a little kid, my dream has been to develop games. Well, now that I am older, more mature, and have some programming experience, I would like to start. However, I would like to turn this into a career.

I would like to develop strategy games like *"Stronghold"* and *"Age of Empires"*.

The problem is that my language of choice is JavaScript.

Comment: The language does not matter. Just do it. :) (Use an engine, don't start from scratch.)

Comment: When you already learned one programming language, then learning another one is not as hard as it seems. The reason is that "programming" and "a programming language" are actually distinct skills. You think you invested a lot of time in learning Javascript, but most of what you learned is actually how to think like a programmer. All programming languages have the same basic building blocks, like variables, branches, loops and functions. Just the syntax looks different.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt What is a good js engine ?

Comment: I don't know sorry. Also, please note that "what technology to use" questions are considered off-topic for this site. (More details in the [help].)

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask about the best engines, but more importantly, it doesn't matter what's best. Just pick one and start. ([This](https://phaser.io/games) is one js engine.) You can pick something else the next project. You're going to be doing many projects not just one.  And you'll likely be using more than one language.

Comment: @Philipp not to be pedantic but purely functional languages like haskell don't have things like loops and variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is correct, language doesn't matter too much. If you are fluent, and know your limitations, nothing can stop you. Javascript is a pretty common language, you'll find tons of examples easily, and will have plenty of people who can answer questions for you. Whether you build your own framework, or use an existing Engine, there are plenty of options open to you. You might enjoy [Unity3d](https://unity3d.com/), which supports "UnityScript"--essentially Javascript with a more classical semantic structure. See [this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) for a quick rundown.

Comment: Great I ll check unityscript, what language do you use ? and why ?

Comment: I use UnityScript mostly. I have also learned C# (Unity's other supported language) though I prefer the former. The reason why--the syntax makes a lot more sense to me. Everything is public by default, declare variables with a declaration keyword (var), no need to designate type, and classes can easily exist in "global space." Not to mention easy Vector editing. A lot of advanced users prefer C#, but really most things are doable in both. UnityScript has a longer compile time, but that isn't much of an issue. Good luck with your endeavors!